# Disk full message when using a COM component in XP Virtual Mode

Tags: com, windows-7, vb6

I have VB6 running inside the Windows XP Virtual Mode.

There are a set of COM components I need to register which live in the source code on the C drive of the host Windows 7 machine.

I can successfully register the assemblies via regsvr32, however when I try to load a project or even add the reference to a new project I get a error message:

**UPDATE**:
Got no useful answers, and found no answers on the web, also found that communication between Virtual PC and host machine terribly slow, dropped the whole lot, now using a Domain connected Windows XP running in Oracle Virtual Box. This is working well.

[image]

Obviously the disk is not actually full, it seems to be a permissions issue however I am able to manually create files in the folder where the assembly lives.

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: What is "full path to assembly.oca"?

Comment: Is the VM trying to access the COM component on the host? What if you copy it to the VM's disk and register it there?